# Which of the following functions is not O(log(N))

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

I got a multiple choice question for computer science class:

Which of the following functions is not `O(log(N))`

1. `log(log(N))`
2. `1000 + log(N)`
3. `1000 log(N)`
4. `log(1000 N)`
5. `log(N^2)`
6. `1000 log(1000 N^1000)`
7. All of the above are `O(log(N))`

Which one is the right answer?

Comment: When improving your question formatting, I edited options 5 and 6 because you had `N2` and `N1000` and I think you meant `N^2` and `N^1000`. If this is not the case, kindly fix it.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct option is 7 - every one of them is `O(log(N))`.

Let's see why:

1. `log(log(N))` - this grows slower than `log(N)`, so technically you can say it is `O(log(N))` (though in practical terms people usually try to get the tightest bound, so you would say it is `O(log(log(N))`). FWIW, you could even say it's `O(N^2)` or `O(N^N)`.
2. `1000 + log(N)` - this clearly is `O(log(N))` - remember that constants are dropped; the term of interest here is `log(N)`.
3. `1000 log(N)` - for the same reason, this is `O(log(N))` (the growing factor is `log(N)`, the constant is negligible in asymptotic analysis).
4. `log(1000 N)` - again, constants...
5. `log(N^2)` - remember that `log(a^b)` is the same as `b log(a)`, so `log(N^2)` is the same as `2 log(N)`, which for the same reasons is `O(log(N))`.
6. `1000 log(1000 N^1000)` - again, this is equivalent to `10^6 log(1000 N)` which is `O(log(N))`.

If for some reason you're still not sure why constants are dropped in asymptotic analysis, you can have a look at [the formal definition of Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), but the intuition behind is that as `N` grows, constant factors easily become (at some point) negligible, so they don't make that much of a difference. The point of Big O analysis is to get a feeling for how the algorithm's running time grows as the input is bigger and bigger.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better.

Comment: So quick, clear and easy understanding response !!  Thanks so much Filipe!

Comment: @Helen I'm glad I could be of help. I wish you the best of luck and success in your class.